# mvc design question

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, design-patterns

I am using Zend framework and doctrine in this app

In my web application i have various individual modules like events, conferences, case studies.. so i am making controller design at this moment. In the below image regulatory document is the controller and its sub are its actions. So regulatory doc, videos, podcasts all are having almost the same kind of functionality. so is this design appropriate...?
In mvc for each action i will be having a separate view. And on user type i may have to put access levels on this modules. so i have kept separate controller so that i can easily control the module for each user type. But this is resulting in duplicate code.

[image]

Now i am thinking to make one parent class and in that i will have all the common methods. eg. I will have common class Resources and in that i will keep list, search, suggest, addFavorite etc. And that will be the parent to the above given controllers.

So than how will i manage my view for all these different modules if i go with this approach..? if i go with this than my code will be bit messy..?

Comment: Can you give an example of "messy" code? Can you be more specific about what you're worried about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have a set of common behaviors among your regulatory documents, videos and podcasts.

In this case you should probably try to abstract the commonalities out into a parent class from which these three areas inherit.

As an example, I have my own MVC framework where I define a superclass tnh_controller from which my other controllers (eg: venue_controller, group_controller) inherit. In the parent controller I define the header() and footer() and delete() methods. I can then use those unchanged in the child classes and save myself some effort.

You can likewise do some of the common work for your models (CRUD) in a model superclass, only overriding it as needed. Most of the logic for different models comes from class variables (table names, column names, etc).

I wouldn't worry too much about being "strict" MVC. Instead try to work out what will save you time and keep your code organized. It sounds like you're on the right track putting similar behaviors at a parent level.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep all the controllers to have nice URLs and clear structure in the modules, however keep the controllers thin. Put your domain logic into Services or Entities, hence no (or just less) code duplication is required.

More in:

- [Is MVC + Service Layer common in zend or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744402/is-mvc-service-layer-common-in-zend-or-php)
- [How to implement service layer in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458195/how-to-implement-service-layer-in-zend-framework)

From DDD:

- http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/118

controllers belong to application layer / domain logic belongs to domain layer

Answer (score 0):

MVC designing means that for each view, you have a controller and a model. However, the models don't need to be classes at all, nor having a different model for each MVC. Usually you will share a model between some MVCs, or your model might just be an integer value which you define in the own controller. Usually, you might even want to share data between them, then you will have a singleton mode:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 0):

You can still have a separate controller to contain  suggest, addFavorite actions without having to make it the parent class for all the controllers. Basically the UI elements related to these you can render as partial views and call on to the actions in the relevant controller. That way you can get rid of the problem with the views.