# Zend_Db_Table and db->select in controller or model

Tags: zend-framework, model, controller, zend-db-table

I'm a little bit confused with Zend. Many examples show the usage of Zend_db_Table in the controller. But from what I've learn about MVC, anything about DB should be in the model. Now that Zend is created and maintain by PHP team, I really don't know what to think, so I follow the rule without asking.

Here is an example of the kind of code I put in the controller for now.

Thanks to anyone who could clarify my doubt.

```
$filter = $this->_getParam('filter', array());
$order_by = $this->_getParam('order_by', 'last_name');
$order = $this->_getParam('order', 'ASC');

// Select
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select('*')->from('contact_address');

// Filter / Where
$where = array();
if(isset($filter['id']) AND $filter['id'] != ""){                                   $select->where('id = ?' , $filter['id']); }
if(isset($filter['title']) AND $filter['title'] != ""){                             $select->where('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) LIKE ?', $filter['title'] . '%'); }
if(isset($filter['phone']) AND preg_match_all('/\d/', $filter['phone'], $matches)){ $select->where('phone LIKE ?', implode('', $matches[0]) . '%'); }
if(isset($filter['email']) AND $filter['email'] != ""){                             $select->where('email LIKE ?', $filter['email'] . '%'); }
if(isset($filter['published']) AND $filter['published'] != ""){                     $select->where('published = ?', $filter['published']); }
else{                                                                               $select->where('published >= 0'); }

// Order
$select->order($order_by . ' ' . $order);
$select->order('last_name ASC');

// Pagination
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page', 1));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($_SESSION['LIMIT_PER_PAGE']);
```

Comment: I prefer to keep any concept of a storage mechanism (DB or otherwise) completely separate from the model. Check out the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Even [Zend recommends](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html) using a combination of [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) to keep your models clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice slideshow about the model part in Zend from a zend guru http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/architecting-your-models. It took me a while to fully understand how Zend sees MVC. We went even one step further and introduced a service layer for inter module communication [How to implement service layer in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458195/how-to-implement-service-layer-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you think is right that most of the interaction with the Db should go into the Model.

But Sometimes the ease of use and simplicity may make it more feasible to run some queries in the controller itself.

However it is completely your choice that how would you want your code to be.

Lets take the example you have given. 
The way you are doing it seems fine, and the same thing you could have achieved it if you created a method in the respective model and called it with the parameters that you get and return the $select variable from there.

Hope it helps.