# Zend Framework 1 Service Layer

Tags: php, zend-framework, service

I know there is a post regarding ZF1 services which is closed but the links are dead.

So my question to you is how to write a zend service for zf1, I saw `Zend_Service_Abstract` but is there any good information on the web about this? How do you initiate it in the bootstrap?

I want to write services for Doctrine, but I just can't find any good information on how to write a zf1 service from top-bottom, not to mention zf docs are really bad.

So where do we need to start when writing a service layer(https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458195/how-to-implement-service-layer-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is answer to your question: 
https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZF1-Doctrine2-ServiceLayer
See the dirs of package and you can easily integrate Doctrine service layer into your (old) zf1 App.

And move on to ZF3.

Comment: Thank you! I can't move to zf3 not my project, but how do I initiate in the controller the servicelocator? I managed to do the setup

Comment: Sorry for late answer.
You can build your own Controller that extends Zend_Controller_Action_Abstract 
and there to getContainer like this $this->getInvokeArg('frontcontroller')->getContainer()->get('Servicename');

Comment: You really should update your codebase to use a newer version of the zend framework. Version 2 is stable. Version 3 is the last version, but it is not so stable at the moment. Changes are on the road since some months. Hope it will be great to switch in some months :)